# What makes this question unclear?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

A few days ago, I asked [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147919/75524) after leaving it in the sandbox for a bit. It got closed as "unclear what you're asking", because I didn't notice something that needed clarification in the sandbox. I edited the question to clarify it, and it got reopened.

What confuses me is that it then got closed again, with the same close reason. Why?

Comment: There are unanswered questions with upvotes (by one of the folks who voted to close) in the comments. Have you addressed them?

Comment: @Poke They were addressed by the edit.

Comment: it is possible to find something wrong in each question, the good one too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the thing which causes most confusing is that, although the meaning you are using for "p-dimensional sub-array" can be inferred through careful analysis of some particular subsections of your challenge, the way you present it is as though this definition is the natural definition for "p-dimensional sub-array" and you're just adding reminders. To me (and apparently several others), an N-dimensional array is not just an array containing other N-1 dimensional arrays, it is a means of representing N-dimensional organization.

For example, in this challenge a 2-dimensional array with 2 elements in each dimension is this: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and if you ask for a 1-dimensional sub-array the challenge is "From this array, pick an element" because it's an array containing 1-dimensional arrays. However, when I am told a 2-dimensional array is defined by `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` the structure it represents to me is

```
1 2
3 4
```

as a single 2-dimensional data structure, not as just some arrays that happen to be indexed. When viewing the 2-dimensional structure, there isn't any intuitive reason [1,2] is a valid 1-dimensional sub-array but [1,3] is not.

It might help if you describe things as "Nested arrays" rather than "N-dimensional arrays" to keep people from expanding the structure, but I think just working through an example in more detail would help explain the flow of logic the most.

Comment: Il pelo nell'uovo si trova in qualunque domanda: Translation: Is it possible to find something wrong in each question, the good one too